# Detect app opening?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a Tab bar app with 3 view controllers and I use "viewWillAppear" to detect which view is opend.

When I close the app, it still works "in the background" and when I open the app again "viewWillAppear" is not detecting this opening.

Is there any other option to detect this opening? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, You should see the necessary delegation method in `UIApplicationDelegate`

- When you close application that currently open, It will call this method:

  `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`
- After the application has been closed but still in dock, you open them again. In the transition state before entering the application, It will call this method:

  `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`
- When the application completely presented on previous state before you closed them. It finally call thid method:

  `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

If you would like to do something in `viewWillAppear` you should implement in `applicationDidBecomeActive` to send some message to your current view or other to do what do you want to do after application became actived.

Comment: can you tell me please or give mi a link to an example of implementing this?

Comment: found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919950/applicationwillenterforeground-reload-data-from-viewcontroller 
Thank's everyone for help

Comment: Is it possible to refresh start ViewControoler in applicationWillEnterForeground? If yes tell me pls how.

Comment: I'm not sure about implementing in applicationWillEnterForeground. If you have a complex refresh code it may cause some problem. For me, I prefer to fire the refresh code in applicationDidBecomeActive. But you can try both method for what is the best for your application.

Answer (score 8):

You can observe the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` or implement `applicationWillEnterForeground:` in your app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is resumed from the background, it will receive the `applicationWillEnterForground:` method. It'll get the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` when it is suspended too.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"app will enter foreground");
[viewController refresh:NULL];
}
```

i think this will work.
write this in your app delegate